# Is a deterministic process adapted?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion on a probability Space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and let $\mathbb F:=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ denote the natural filtration, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(W_s: \ 0\leq s\leq t) \vee\mathcal{N}$.

My question is simple: If $f(s)$ is a deterministic process, for example $f(s) = e^{t-s}$. Is $f$ adapted to $\mathbb F$?

Thank you! :)

Comment: If $f(s)=c$ for some constant $c$, is $f$ adapted to $\mathcal{F}$? (Or asked the other way round: When is a stochastic process called adapted? What's the definition?)

Comment: I would believe so.. being $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted means that there is a measurable function $G$ such that $f(t) = G(W_t)$ and if $f(t)=c$ we can indeed define $G=c$ as such function, can't we? Moreover, I add the null-sets to the filtration so constants should be measurable w.r.t. all sigma algebras $\mathcal{F}_t$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't agree with your definition of being $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted. If $f(t) = G(W_t)$, then $f$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted, but not every $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted process is of this form. How about $$f(s) := \begin{cases} W_s & s \leq t_0 \\ W_{t_0} & s>t_0 \end{cases},$$ is this process adapted? And, does it admit such a representation? (Here $t_0>0$ is some fixed constant.)

Comment: It isn't. $f(s)$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable for all $0<s<t_0$ but not more? after $t_0$ $f(s) = W_{t_0}$ which is an $\mathcal{F}_{t_0}$-measurable r.v.

Comment: No, it is adapted. The point is that $$\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(W_s; s \leq t) \cup \mathcal{N},$$ which means that $f$ may not only depend on $W_t$ but also on the past (i.e. $W_s$ for $s \leq t$). Moreover, note that $\mathcal{F}_{t_0} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_s$ for any $s \geq t_0$. So, since $f(t_0)$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_0}$-measurable, this implies in particular that $f(s) = f(t_0)$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable for any $s \geq t_0$.

Comment: Aha so in my "definition" above I actually should have written $f(t) = G(W_{\cdot})$? In any case, deterministic and constant processes are adapted too right?

Comment: Yes, constant and deterministic processes are adapted (see my answer below). And no, $f(t) = G(W_{\cdot})$ is rather misleading. $f$ is adapted if it $f(t)$ does only depend on the path of the process up to time $t$. (In contrast, $G(W_{\cdot})$ means that it may depend on the whole path.)

Comment: Yes I realized that mistake :) I meant exactly that. Thank you very much really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process $f: [0,\infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-adapted if, and only if, $$(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_s) \ni \omega \mapsto f(s,\omega)$$ is measurable for any fixed $s \geq 0$, i.e. if

$$\{\omega \in \Omega; f(s,\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}_s \quad \text{for any Borel set} \, B.$$

For fixed $ \geq 0$, the function

$$\omega \mapsto f(s,\omega) = e^{t-s}, \qquad \omega \in \Omega,$$

is simply a constant (it does not depend on $\omega$). It is widely known that constant functions are measurable with respect to any $\sigma$-algebra; hence in particular with respect to $\mathcal{F}_s$. This already proves that $f$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-adapted.

Comment: Of course, I see it much clearer :) Thank you very much. I guess it is then correct that: "being $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable" is equivalent with: "there is a measurable function s.t. $f(s) = G(W_{\leq s})$ then? :)

Comment: @mark I'm not sure right now whether it is equivalent; it might be a little more complicated. But from the practical point of view, i.e. if you want to find out whether a given process is adapted, then this exactly the condition you have to check.